# Using defaults values for scoped route in Rails 4 always overrides default_url_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, scope

I am trying to implement an **optional** "region" parameter in my urls in my existing app:

Existing:
/blogs

New:
/se/blogs
or
/en/blogs

This route should be optional (it will only be used as a filter, no region means world wide), and the parameter value should be either 'ww' (world wide) or nil (or whatever, as long as I know none is provided).

The route I came up with looks like this:

```
scope "(:region)", region: /en|se|dk|no|ww/, defaults: {region: 'ww'}
```

I use default_url_options in ApplicationController to set the :region parameter to the same as param[:region] so that it's being retained if it exists and should be added to all the urls on the page.

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { region: params[:region] }
end
```

The issue is that when I use the url /se/blogs the parameter is correctly set to 'se' but it's not being added to any urls on the page automatically. If I remove the defaults option to the scoped route it works and prepends the parameter 'se' but then, because there is no default value, many urls fail with 'ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches' because in the url helper the object is taking the region value since there is no default value.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Could it be related to this (still unsolved) issue?
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12178

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the default region that way doesn't appear to work; however, according to the Guides, it should:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults

Why not drop the default if `nil` is an acceptable value?

**config/routes.rb**

```
scope "(:region)", region: /en|se|dk|no|ww/ do
  resources :blogs
end
```

As a workaround, you could set a default region like so:

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { region: params[:region] || "ww" }
end
```

**Update:**

Without a default region:

**config/routes.rb**

```
scope "(:region)", region: /en|se|dk|no/ do
  resources :blogs do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { region: params[:region] }
end
```

In your view:

```
<% @blog.posts.each do |post|
  <%= link_to post.title, blog_post_path(@blog, post) %>
<% end %>
```

URL when no region is specified:

```
/blogs/1/posts/1
```

URL when `en` region is specified:

```
/en/blogs/1/posts/1
```

**Update #2:**

Ok, I was able to reproduce your failing test. This is caused by a Rails bug and it's the same one you mentioned in your question. You can read more about the issue and some workarounds here:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255

To get your tests passing, one approach is to initialize the `region` option in `default_url_options` using a `before(:all)` block. Try adding the following to your RSpec configuration:

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    default_url_options[:region] = nil
  end
end
```

You'll probably want to restrict that block to `feature` and `controller` group types.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jordan! The issue with not providing the default value to the region seems to be that my current routes, such as blog_post_path(@blog, @post) puts the @blog in the region parameter and essentially missing one parameter (one gets chewed up by the :region it seems). Not sure if there is a way around that, but even so I'd like to not display the 'ww' in the route, just have it in the params when the request implicitly if none is provided without redirects or anything like that and if one is provided it should override the default as expected.

Comment: And I too think this should be possible according to the guides. Question is if this is not possible in any other way, would I file a bug report? I started looking through the Rails code for some sort of fix but I'm not that experienced with the code base to not risk breaking something else.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your issue. I've updated my answer, showing how to avoid using a default region. You can't have a value in `params[:region]` without it displaying in your route. Why do you need 'ww'?

Comment: If you feel it's a bug, you can open a new issue at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues. That's probably the best way to get feedback in this case.

Comment: I might do that, your edit here seems to do the trick though and is what I want. I had this solution first and it seemed fine, but now tons of tests fail with the error in my original post. Maybe rspec is the real issue here. Sigh.

Comment: The error is listed below, and as you see there, the blog_id is left empty and the region takes the blog object. The original url for this is: blog_feed_path(@blog) (a named route).

No route matches {:action=>"feed", :blog_id=>nil, :controller=>"blogs", :format=>nil, :region=>#<Blog id: 78 [...]

Comment: I reproduced your failing test. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yep, this is what I just did on my end as well :) Last one was a failing link in an email. Thanks for your help, I'll mark this as the solution since it's the closest we're gonna get.

Comment: Just a side note, would you agree that the defaults hash (in the scoped route) should be overwritten by default_url_options and if so, that should solve this issue as well since the route would set the parameter and not ActionController, which RSpec doesn't seem to use?

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam, but model specs fail with the current solution because they don't use default_url_options. An alternative would be: default_url_options[:region] = nil if defined?(default_url_options)

Comment: you can restrict the block to a group type. E.g. `config.before(:each, type: :feature)`

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer keeping your existing route `/blogs`, and just add an optional parameter called `region` or something.

So the url would be like `/blogs?region=se` or `/blogs?region=en`

Then in your `controller`, you just need to apply different code based on `params[:region]`

Much easier, and more constant url structure.

Comment: Sorry, has to be first part of the URL like described.